# Populate a SQL table: Error - Exception calling "..." with "0" argument(s)

Tags: sql, json, powershell

I'm trying to populate a SQL table using an API with PowerShell.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME; Integrated Security=SSPI")  
$conn.open()
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$request = 'http://data.website.com/api/'
If ($JSONResult.success){
    $JSONResult.rates.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'date'          = $JSONResult.date
            'timestamp'     = $JSONResult.timestamp
            'base'          = $JSONResult.base
            'currency'      = $_.name
            'rate'          = $_.value
        }
    } | select date,timestamp,base,currency,rate|ft -auto
}
foreach($obj in $JSONResult) {
    $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ExRate VALUES (@Date, @Timestamp, @Base, @Currency, @Rate)"
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date",     $obj.date);
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Timestam", $obj.timestamp);
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Base",     $obj.base);
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Currency", $obj.currency);
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rate",     $obj.rate);
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $cmd.Parameters.clear();
}
$conn.Close()
```

This is the error I am getting:
[image: This is the error I am getting]

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The parameterized query '(@Date nvarchar(10),@Timestamp int,@Base nvarchar(3),@Currency n' expects the parameter '@Currency' which was not supplied."

Comment: I would look to see what your data needs to look like for the currency value ---- Not sure if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The data is right I think the problem is 'currency' = $_.name and 'rate'=$_.value it can be different way to get this values which I'm not sure how thanks though  - Thom Schumacher

Comment: do you have an example of this object: $JSONResult.rates.PSObject.Properties

Comment: Did you mean the JSON file? {
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1519296206,
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2018-06-20",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.566015,
        "CAD": 1.560132,
        "CHF": 1.154727,
        "CNY": 7.827874,
        "GBP": 0.882047,
        "JPY": 132.360679,
        "USD": 1.23396,
    [...]
    }
} `

Comment: based on that data my object looks like this:   success   : True
timestamp : 1519296206
base      : EUR
date      : 2018-06-20
rates     : @{AUD=1.566015; CAD=1.560132; CHF=1.154727; CNY=7.827874; GBP=0.882047; JPY=132.360679; USD=1.23396} rates has different rates for each country I assume right?  if so which rate is it you want in your currency item?? all the rates one of them?

Comment: Each country has different value because the Base is EUR and yes I want all of them to populate in SQL table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want I moved rates.psobject.Properties to be piped to the foreach:

```
$j = '{ "success": true, "timestamp": 1519296206, "base": "EUR", "date": "2018-06-20", "rates": { "AUD": 1.566015, "CAD": 1.560132, "CHF": 1.154727, "CNY": 7.827874, "GBP": 0.882047, "JPY": 132.360679, "USD": 1.23396 } } '      
$j2 = $J |convertfrom-json  
$results = $j2.rates.psobject.Properties | foreach {

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{ 
    'date'          = $($j2.date) 
    'timestamp'     = $($j2.timestamp)
    'base'          = $($j2.base )
    'currency'      = $_.name 
    'rate'          = $_.value 
} 
}
```

Results look like this:

```
date      : 2018-06-20
currency  : AUD
timestamp : 1519296206
rate      : 1.566015
base      : EUR

date      : 2018-06-20
currency  : CAD
timestamp : 1519296206
rate      : 1.560132
base      : EUR

date      : 2018-06-20
currency  : CHF
timestamp : 1519296206
rate      : 1.154727
base      : EUR

date      : 2018-06-20
currency  : CNY
timestamp : 1519296206
rate      : 7.827874
base      : EUR

date      : 2018-06-20
currency  : GBP
timestamp : 1519296206
rate      : 0.882047
base      : EUR

date      : 2018-06-20
currency  : JPY
timestamp : 1519296206
rate      : 132.360679
base      : EUR

date      : 2018-06-20
currency  : USD
timestamp : 1519296206
rate      : 1.23396
base      : EUR
```

Remainder of the code

```
foreach($obj in $results) { 
    $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ExRate VALUES (@Date, @Timestamp, @Base, @Currency, @Rate)" 
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date",     $obj.date); 
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Timestamp", $obj.timestamp); 
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Base",     $obj.base); 
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Currency", $obj.currency); 
    $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rate",     $obj.rate); 
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    $cmd.Parameters.clear(); 
    } 
    $conn.Close()
```

Comment: Thom, I can get these result even with my code but when trying to populate the sql table is not getting currency and rate that's the problem    `'currency'      = $_.name` 
`'rate'              = $_.value`

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: The $($j2.date) timestamp and others will more than likely work with just $j2.date and no $().

Comment: `{
  "meta": {
    "effective_params": {
      "data_set": "Website",
      "base_currencies": [
        "USD"
      ]
    },
    "endpoint": "spot",
    "request_time": "2018-06-20T18:06:59+00:00",
    "skipped_currency_pairs": []
  },
  "quotes": [
    {
      "base_currency": "USD",
      "quote_currency": "AUD",
      "bid": "1.35494",
      "ask": "1.35516",
      "midpoint": "1.35505"
    },
    {
      "base_currency": "USD",
      "quote_currency": "BRL",
      "bid": "3.75455",
      "ask": "3.75705",
      "midpoint": "3.75580"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Thom, I got one more question for different JSON pipeline I am trying to learn how to get other pipelines for example if I want these result below from above JSON I posted how my code should be thanks in advance                                                                                                   `request_time   :2018-06-20T18:06:59+00:00
base_currency  : USD
quote_currency : ZAR
bid            : 13.6187
ask            : 13.6276
midpoint       : 13.6232`